# React UseState hook for updating data - CRUD

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, crud, use-state

Im just wondering if anyone could point out where im going wrong with my code.
Im relativly new to react so began with a simple todo list.
I then edited this to allow for various other forms such as menu, profile etc.
Below is the code attached for the menu section.
My back end works if I use postmaster which leads me to believe its my front end, and specifically my useState.
I can call the data and view it within my modal and it appears, however, I cant seem to edit the specific data within the form field and/or post it to my database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ive attached my code below.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

const EditMenu = ({ menu }) => {
    //editText function    
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(menu.item_title, menu.item_price, menu.item_description, menu.item_category);
    const { title, category, price, description } = inputs;
    const onChange = e =>
        setInputs({ ...inputs, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    const editMenuItem = async (item_id) => {
        try {
            const body = { title, category, price, description };
            const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/menu/${item_id}`, {
                method: "PUT",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            });
            window.location = "/admin";
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target={`#id${menu.item_id}`}>Edit</button>
            {/*id = "id21"*/}
            <div className="modal" id={`id${menu.item_id}`} onClick={() => setInputs(menu.item_title, menu.item_price, menu.item_description, menu.item_category)}>
                <div className="modal-dialog">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h4 className="modal-title">Edit Menu</h4>
                            <button className="close btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={() => setInputs(menu.item_title, menu.item_price, menu.item_description, menu.item_category)}>&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" className="form-control my-3" value={menu.item_title} onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
                            <input type="tel" name="price" placeholder="Price" className="form-control my-3" value={menu.item_price} onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
                            <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description" className="form-control my-3" value={menu.item_description} onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
                            <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="Category" className="form-control my-3" value={menu.item_category} onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={() => editMenuItem(menu.item_id)}>Edit</button>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={() => setInputs(menu.item_title, menu.item_price, menu.item_description, menu.item_category)}>Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Fragment>

    );
};
```

Update,
Ive tried various suggested fixes using the below answers so far.
Both of these fixes allow the form fields to be editable, and the information within the form fields changes and thus within the state also however it is not sent to the database. Upon refresh of the page, the old information is pulled from the database.

Ive discovered that if I removed all of the form fields but one, it successfully updates AND sends to the database.
Title OR Description OR Price OR Category.
Checking the network tab within the browser whilst updating shows that for more than one input field, the put request fails and no information/payload is sent to the body within the request tab.

As a result, the database returns a NOT NULL error.
Based off Oliviers answer below, that setInput is only recognises one parameter, I can only imagine that this is what is breaking when there is more than one form field/input added. I unfortunatly dont know enough react to know if this is the case or not.

Comment: Great question! What did you try out to solve your problem?

Comment: Ive updated my useState formatting based off the below answers. This has allowed met to edit the information. If I try edit again, the information is still changed in the form, however upon a refresh, the old info is still being pulled from the database. The new info is not sending to it.
Not null error in item_title colum appears. 
After checking naming conventions, and removing all fields but one, it does work, however only title OR description OR price.
Olivier below said my setInputs only accepts one parameter so i guess this is why. Currently struggling on how to fix that issue now.

Comment: Could you add what you attempted to your question instead of adding it as a comment? I believe that Olivier Boissé's answer probably does the trick. They suggests in their answer to use an object for your input.

Comment: No problem. Apologies. Ive updated the code section in my question to reflect the changes Olivier suggested and removed the MenuList code as it appears it was irrelevant for the problem.

Comment: No worries! I was not suggesting to change the code but instead explain in your question what you had tried to fix your issue. Could you revert your code snippet to what it was minus the MenuList code?

Comment: Ah my mistake, first time using SO. Ive changed my original code back and added in the updates that ive tried at the bottom, and what Ive newly discovered along the way since then.

Comment: Don't sweat it! Your changes are a little overkill but I suspect that more is better.  Welcome to Stack Overflow! I hope you'll find a good and helpful community here.

Comment: Cheers. Mind if I ask Overkill how?  I haven't managed to find a solution yet as the provided answers haven't worked. Any help at all might set me in the right direction.

Comment: For sure! I suspect that it is not necessary to edit questions with the code that was suggested in answers as that code is already visible in the answers. I'm sorry to hear you haven't found a fix to your problem. I'm sure you'll find a solution!

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem in your state initialization => `const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(menu.item_title, menu.item_price, menu.item_description, menu.item_category);` is not correct, `useState` take a single parameter, here you must build an object representing the inputs.

Here is a solution using a function to initialize the `inputs` state, to prevent computing the object each time the component is re-rendered

```
function buildInputs(menu) {
  return {
    title: menu.item_title,
    category: menu.item_category,
    price: menu.item_price,
    description: menu.item_description
  };
}

const EditMenu = ({ menu }) => {
  //editText function
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(() => buildInputs(menu));
  const { title, category, price, description } = inputs;

  // Needed if you want the inputs to be updtated when the menu property is updated
  useEffect(() => setInputs(buildInputs(menu)), [menu]);

  const onChange = e => setInputs({ ...inputs, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  ...
```

You must also change the input value to reflect the state variable :

```
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" 
       className="form-control my-3" value={title} onChange={onChange} />
```

Comment: Similiar to the other answer, Im being returned the error of 'null value in column "item_title" violates not-null constraint' when I apply this fix with the function and useEffect. 
The information in the form itself updates, but doesnt seem to send to the database.

Comment: check in your browser if the input values are sent when you trigger a `PUT` http request

Comment: I just had a look, they are not.

Comment: what is the value of the `body` variable ? I edited my answer, you might have a problem with the input value, try `value={title}` instead of `value={menu.item_title}`

Comment: hmm unfortunatly still the same issue.
Im not sure if I commented earlier, with regards to initialisation, I have another component called MenuList which uses this edit component. Would that have any impact on your earlier answer? 
Ive added it below my code also.

Comment: no impact I think. You might have a problem with you setInputs, I see in your code `onClick={() => setInputs(menu.item_title, menu.item_price, menu.item_description, menu.item_category)` on the modal which is not correct. As I already sais before, setInputs take a single parameter (which is an object in your case). I don't know why you have an `onclick` handler on this div

Comment: the onclick handler was to ensure that if the user  began to edit the fields and then clicked off the modal, the X or close buttons, that the information would return to the previous state rather than be left with what they have changed when they next open it.

Comment: Thanks for your help bud. It didnt fix my problem but it did get me thinking about it. In the end you were correct about the single parameter. Once I got my head around that, I was able to fix it by splitting my setInputs into individual useStates into setTitle, setDescription, setPrice and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your state like this:

```
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
     title: menu.item_title,
     price: menu.item_price,
     category: menu.item_category,
     description: menu.item_description
  });
```

also you need to change value attributes to be variables rather than setting them to the menu values, for example:

```
//code
<input name="title" value={inputs.title} onChange={onChange}/>
```

cause values inside inputs are changeable by your onChange method, on the other hand, values inside menu object will remain with the same values.

Comment: This has allowed me to edit the form fields thankfully, however, when i click edit, im returned with an error of 'null value in column "item_title" violates not-null constraint' and the information has not changed in the database only the form. Upon refresh its back to the old information again called from the db.

Comment: if the column name is item_title, you should rename the field in your inputs to match that, I didn't mention anything about sending data, but of course you need to set correct names, my answer was about useState hook, i hope this is clear enough

Comment: It works while sending a single field succh as title OR description OR price, but not multiple. Olivier above told me that my setInputs only takes a single parameter, which I imagine is the reason having multiple wont work. I can only assume theres an error or im doing something wrong within the react code itself somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out the issue.
By splitting my setInput useState into seperate individual useStates, I was able to get it to work.

So my origional code of...

```
const EditMenu = ({ menu }) => { 
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(menu.item_title, menu.item_price, menu.item_description, menu.item_category);
    const { title, category, price, description } = inputs;
```

changed to this.

```
const EditMenu = ({ menu }) => { 
    const [item_title, setTitle] = useState(menu.item_title);
    const [item_price, setPrice] = useState(menu.item_price);
    const [item_description, setDescription] = useState(menu.item_description);
```

and the onChange function and form input...

```
const onChange = e =>
        setInputs({ ...inputs, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
<input... onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
```

changed to this...

```
value={item_title} onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
value={item_price} onChange={e => setPrice(e.target.value)} />
value={item_description} onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)} />
```

In the end, Oliviers reasoing was correct even if the soloution didnt work for me. That my setInput only allowed for one parameter. Splitting it up allowed me to pass the remaining parameters.
Thank you everyone for the help, hopefully this might help someone else some day too!